# How to handle disconnection of clients on server

Tags: go, grpc

I am building a monitoring system using gRPC. For that, I need to know if a gRPC client is crashed and thus has disconnected from the gRPC server.

This is how I created my server.

```
var kaep = keepalive.EnforcementPolicy{
    MinTime:             5 * time.Second, // If a client pings more than once every 5 seconds, terminate the connection
    PermitWithoutStream: true,            // Allow pings even when there are no active streams
}

var kasp = keepalive.ServerParameters{
    MaxConnectionIdle:     15 * time.Second, // If a client is idle for 15 seconds, send a GOAWAY
    MaxConnectionAgeGrace: 5 * time.Second,  // Allow 5 seconds for pending RPCs to complete before forcibly closing connections
    Time:                  5 * time.Second,  // Ping the client if it is idle for 5 seconds to ensure the connection is still active
    Timeout:               1 * time.Second,  // Wait 1 second for the ping ack before assuming the connection is dead
}

    s := grpc.NewServer(grpc.KeepaliveEnforcementPolicy(kaep), grpc.KeepaliveParams(kasp))
    pb.RegisterHeartbeatGRPCServer(s, bt)
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
```

I found out that the concept of keep-alive might come in handy to detect disconnected clients.
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/keepalive.md

However, I am not sure how to handle disconnects.

How can handle such disconnects? More precisely, I want to call a function `ClientDisconnected(clientId)` whenever a client has disconnected. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a stats handler for that.  In particular, you're looking for ConnEnd actions:

https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/stats#ConnEnd
https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/stats#Handler (TagConn and HandleConn are what you're looking for)
https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#StatsHandler